# set selected value for DropDownListFor with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a country drop down and a ajax post. when user key in some ID and this will auto trigger the ajax post. other fields like name and address are populated to the field. But not the DropDownListFor for the country field. Anyone could help will really appreciate. i tried a lot of other solution but all failed.

**Ajax post**

```
  function getmachineinfo(serial)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getmachine", "JuraServicing")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { "serial": serial },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#customer_name').val(data.name);
            $('#Customer_address_1').val(data.address1);
            $('#customer_address_2').val(data.address2);

            //$('#country option[value="China"]').attr("selected", "selected");
           // $("#country").val(data.country);
            $("#country").val(data.country).change();
           // $('#country').val("China").attr("selected", "selected");
            //$('#country').val(data.country).attr("selected", "selected");
            //$('select[name^="country"] option[value="Singapore"]').attr("selected", "selected");
        },
        error: function (err) {

        }
    });

}
```

**HTMl** i have both "Text" and "Value" in the select list

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.country,(ViewBag.countrylist as SelectList), htmlAttributes: new { @class = " form-control col-md-3" })
```

**added controller**

```
 ViewBag.countrylist  = new SelectList(db.countryLists, "Country", "Country", "Singapore");
```

**problem found**
because there is a space in the database list stored in the database causing the data to mismatch

Comment: What does the data you are getting back look like? Is the dropdown populated with the value and text in the right place?

Comment: What is the value of `data.country`? And does it match one of the values of your options in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Yes it matched and both text and value are in place. Even i hardcode the value in jquery also didnt populated

Comment: `$("#country").val(data.country)` should work as long as `data.country` expression's value is same as `value` attribute value of one of the options in the SELECT element. Do you have any script errors in your page ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting back data that looks like this:

```
[{countryName: countryText, countryId: countryValue},...]
```

What you can do in the success case to populated the dropdown is:

```
for(var v in result){
  countryDropdown.append("<option>", {value: result[v].countryId, text: result[v].countryName});
}
```

Then to pick a selected value for the dropdown, you can say:

```
countryDropdown.val("specificCountryId");
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the problem.
during importing of the country list to database. There is a space added to the front of each country.

country table store as " Singapore" database saved by the user is "Singapore".
thats why the data mismatch..

thanks everyone for helping